# Can't print reports from SalesEditLines form

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, cil, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

When I trying to print reports from SalesEditLines form (e.g InvoiceForPayment) I have this error:

> Stack trace: Invalid attempt to call SalesFormLetter_Invoice4Paym_RU.new running in CIL on the client.
>    "Microsoft.Dynamics.Ax.Xpp.InvalidRemoteCallException".
>
> в
>   Dynamics.Ax.Application.SalesFormLetter_Invoice4Paym_RU.new(String
>   _className, String _methodName, SysOperationExecutionMode _executionMode, Boolean , Boolean , Boolean )
>
> в
>   Dynamics.Ax.Application.SalesFormLetter_Invoice4Paym_RU..ctor(String
>   _className, String _methodName, SysOperationExecutionMode _executionMode, Boolean , Boolean , Boolean )
>
> в Dynamics.Ax.Application.SalesFormLetter_Invoice4Paym_RU..ctor()
>
> в
>   SalesFormLetter_Invoice4Paym_RU::SalesFormLetter_Invoice4Paym_RU(Object[]
>   )
>
> в
>   Microsoft.Dynamics.Ax.Xpp.ReflectionCallHelper.MakeNewObjCall(Type
>   type, Object[] parameters)
>
> в Microsoft.Dynamics.Ax.Xpp.DictClass.MakeObjectOfXppType(Object[]
>   varArgs, String typeName)
>
> в
>   Dynamics.Ax.Application.SysOperationServiceController.runServiceOperation(Object[]
>   parameters) в
>   SysOperationServiceController.runServiceOperation.xpp:строка 11
>
> в SysOperationServiceController::runServiceOperation(Object[] )
>
> в
>   Microsoft.Dynamics.Ax.Xpp.ReflectionCallHelper.MakeStaticCall(Type
>   type, String MethodName, Object[] parameters)
>
> в Dynamics.Ax.Application.SysDictClass.invokeStaticMethod(Object[]
>   _params) в SysDictClass.invokeStaticMethod.xpp:строка 26
>
> в SysDictClass::invokeStaticMethod(Object[] )
>
> в
>   Microsoft.Dynamics.Ax.Xpp.ReflectionCallHelper.MakeStaticCall(Type
>   type, String MethodName, Object[] parameters)
>
> в Microsoft.Dynamics.Ax.Xpp.PredefinedFunctions.runAsInvoke(String
>   className, String staticMethodName, Object[] parms, Object[]&
>   exportInfolog)

But All code is standard, except InvoiceForPayment report

Comment: Did you try to do a complete CIL compile?

Comment: Yes, but its dint help